# How to condense Section Header in a single line?

Tags: section-titles

I want to get my section header as a single line, but it jumpped to a next line as shown. How to fix it?
[image: section title]

**This is the template I'm using.**

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=10in,paperwidth=8in, inner=20mm, outer=70mm, bottom=30mm, top=20mm,    marginparsep=5mm,   marginparwidth=50mm}


\definecolor{inchworm}{rgb}{0.7, 0.93, 0.36}

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
{\large\bfseries%
    \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=inchworm,right color=white,] (-0.1,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
{\thesection}%                   
{1em}%
{#1}



\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section{Common Logarithm and Natural Logarithm}
\marginnote{
    \begin{center}

        The logarithm of $N$ to the base 10 $(\log_{10}N)$ is said to be a common logarithm, 
        and is usually written as $\log N$ (omitting the base)

\end{center}}[-8ex]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example which illustrates your problem?

Comment: This is the command I used for section

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
{\large\bfseries%
 \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=inchworm,right color=white,] (-0.1,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
{\thesection}%                   
{1em}%
{#1}

Comment: Could you please create a complete small document that allows others to reproduce the output you get? Linebreaks might depend on the documentclass, font size, margins,... that you use.

Comment: The section title currently can't fit into the textwidth. (Add the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package to see a visual representation of the textblock and the margins.)

Comment: Try to rephrase title, to something as `\section{Common and Natural Algorithm}` ... or you may looking for ragged right section title? In this case add to document preamble `\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedright}`

Comment: I dont't understand, what result you are expecting. Your section title is to long to be in a single line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcJFO.png Could you explain, what result you wish. Do you want to decrease the font size? Or do you want to reduce the margin on the right side? Or do you want to do something else?

Comment: You can make it fit in a single line if you put the section numbers in the margin.

Comment: Writing `\def\bfdefault{b}` somewhere in your preamble can help sometimes. But in your case I still get an overfull hbox. Therefore, rephrasing the given title, changing the margins of your document or decreasing the font size is probably a better way.